# -25 is listed as an even number in Java

Tags: java

I was writing a program to print out only even numbers from an array of integers.

Here is the code below:

```
public class ForLoopExample3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = {7, 6, 9, -2, 8, 12, 17, -25, 15, 18, 21, 13};

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if((arr[i] % 2) > 0)
                continue;
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program above, I get the following output:

[image]

So the question is why is -25 being displayed among the even numbers?

Comment: Probably since -25 % 2 is -1, and therefore not greater than zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-25 mod 2` is `-1`, so your if() test succeeds: the value is NOT greater than 0. You should be testing for `!= 0` instead.

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with how the `%` modulus operator works in Java.  The sign of the result of this operator cannot be the opposite of the original number.  That is, if the original number is negative, then the modulus would be 0 or negative.

According to the [JLS, Section 15.17.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3),

> It follows from this rule that the result of the remainder operation can be negative only if the dividend is negative, and can be positive only if the dividend is positive. Moreover, the magnitude of the result is always less than the magnitude of the divisor.

You're getting `-1`, not `1` from the result of `-25 % 2`, and your print statement executes.

Check if the remainder is not equal to zero instead.

```
if((arr[i] % 2) != 0)
     continue;
```

Or, to eliminate the `continue`...

```
if((arr[i] % 2) == 0)
{
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace '>' to '!=' . Here '((arr[i] % 2) != 0' would mean remainder not equal to zero, and in this case you would continue. Else you would print.

Answer (score 0):

If you print `-25 % 2` you will get `-1` and since your condition is

```
if((arr[i] % 2) > 0)
```

when that operation is zero or less, it will print it as *even*, which is incorrect. You should check if the operation is equal to `0` or not. Zero for even numbers, otherwise, it's odd:

```
if ((arr[i] % 2) == 0)
    // even
else
    // odd
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because -25 % 2  = -1 and -1 < 0

Answer (score 0):

You mod statement should be != 0 not > 0.   -25 % 2 = -1.